# spark read from hdfs with kerberos and write on local filesystem

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kerberos

I am trying to get the following use case:

1. spark read files from HDFS with Kerberos in parquet format
2. spark write this files in csv format

If I write to hdfs, it works perfectly. If I try to write to local filesystem, it doesn´t work: `"main" java.io.IOException: Can't get Master Kerberos principal for use as renewer`

I am using Spark 1.6.2.

To sumarize, my code is

```
val dfIn = sqc.read.parquet(pathIsilon)
dfIn.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(pathFilesystem)
```

Comment: Have you tried to collect the result back to the driver (it's not the best idea though)? Alternatively, pre-append "file://" to your pathFileSystem while saving.

Comment: I dont like this solution because it is unclear. I think the problem is the RDD because problably it doesn't know how to read from one source and write to another source. If this is true, Have I always to collect? It doesn't make sense.